# Volumetric shading on a mesh

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, volumetrics

The gif below is a breakdown of the volumetric hair shading of the titular character from the Dreamworks film Ruby Gillman: Teenage Kraken. I'm wondering how I can apply volumetric shading and a transmissive surface to a mesh using Eevee and Cycles.
[image: Hair volume breakdown]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You have a _Principled Volume_ node in the _Shader Editor_ and the _Principled BSDF_ node has settings for _Transmission_, _Specular_ and _Clearcoat_ as well. Or do you need to know how to setup a material in general? The problem with _Eevee_ will be that it does not work with volumetrics in shape of a mesh, it will always fill the entire cuboid bounding box.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I'm getting to know materials and rendering in Blender.